# How can a solar battery charger without separate load connection include three stage charging?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller

As you may know, there are several solar battery chargers (e.g. mppt Victronenergy ones) that only provide **2 connections, one to the battery and one to the solar panels**. So, no separate load connection. These are made especially for when you have an external low volt protection and/or only a converter put directly on the battery (which have their own LVP). (As said by Victron themselves on their forum.)
But how does it know **how much the current is** during charging since it could be current going to your load through the converter and not just into your battery? (They are in parallel!) Especially since you could be switching things on and off and appliances need different currents at different times (e.g. fridge).

Sounds like not the optimum three stage charging cycle to me.

Worst of all is some fabricants don't even provide charger versions with separate load connections above 20A, like Victron.

Anyone more info on this?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing - a charger on a battery that's in use can only be truly effective if it knows the final battery current. I suppose the truth is that an almost-full battery used for occational large loads (radio transmitter, engine starting) can tolerate moderate abuse like this, and the charger can just drop down a stage or two and move up again if the voltage doesn't drop for any reason.

Comment: AFAIK (I own both a Victron MPPT and a Victron Battery Monitor), if you also own a Victron Battery Monitor (e.g. BMV7xx), it can communicate with an MPPT controller via a bluetooth [VE.Smart network](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Manual-VE.Smart-Networking-EN.pdf). The BMV monitors the actual current going into the battery, the voltage at the battery poles and the battery's temperature and the MPPT can take that into account. That said, an MPPT controller also functions perfectly fine without being connected to a BMV.

Answer (score 2):

### Voltage winds up being the arbiter.

If the load is more than is available from solar, the battery will be discharging and voltage will drop below battery float.

If load is less than is available from solar, the battery will continue charging, and system voltage will rise until it reaches normal battery float voltage, and then the charge controller will reduce current to keep it from going higher. It will take just enough from the solar panels to serve the load.

Reducing draw from the solar panels will of course knock it off MPPT and cause solar panel voltage to rise somewhat.  However solar panels are linear enough that a happy spot is found with solar voltage vs current.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this only explains the last stage in a 3 stage charging. But not if to go into first or second, neither how to keep current and voltage of ONLY the battery perfect for first two stages.

Comment: @e-motive, a 3 stage or 5 stage charger has different voltage levels for the stages, and also is a state-machine: it knows what stage you came from, and what stage is next.